# How to get the arc length of a real-valued function in 3D.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

The definition of arc length of a parametric function is given by 
$$\int|r'(t)|dt=\int\sqrt{[x'(t)]^2+[y'(t)]^2+[z'(t)]^2} dt$$

So I guess what I'm asking is how do I use a function like $z=\cos(x)+\sin(y)$ with this definition? I am aware that $z(x,y)$ is a surface, but is it possible to find the distance between two points through the surface using this definition? If not, then how do I go about doing so?

---

Example:

[image: $z=\cos(x)+\sin(y)$]
If I were an ant along this surface, how would I find the distance needed to travel between one of the peaks and wells in this graph?

Comment: By "distance" do you mean shortest distance or something that is specified by a path $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the shortest path between two points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ **along** the surface of the graph. It's as if I'm taking a slice of the surface and calculating the arc length of that slice.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Geodesic.html

Comment: Also, what kind of "slice" are you referring to? A straight line may not give you the shortest distance.

Comment: arggg... Is it really as complicated as a geodesic? I guess so... darn. Why didn't I see it before.... Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I meant taking a line curve from the surface and finding the arc length of that line curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering to get this out of the “unanswered” queue:*

Finding the shortest distance between two points on an arbitrary surface is asking for a [geodesic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) connecting these points. Computing geodesics can be quite complicated, depending on how your surface is given. There is literature available on the subject, which I won't copy into this answer.